# Equilibrium equations in Grand Canonical Ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm starting to study grand canonical ensemble, the equilibrium between phases and phase transitions, looking for the critical point. By now I'm working with two spices (and latter with three) and I want to compute the equilibrium equation between gas (ideal gas) and a solid (using Einstein solid model), and also find the critical temperature. With this two phases in a box with an ideal model I have the grand partition functions
$$  \mathbb{Z}_g = \exp[e^{\beta \mu_g} \cdot Z_g] \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{Z}_s = \exp[e^{\beta \mu_s} \cdot Z_s] $$
where I have the canonical partition function
$$ Z_g = \frac{V_g}{\Lambda} \quad \quad \quad Z_s = \frac{1}{2\cdot\sinh(\frac{1}{2} \beta \hbar \omega )} $$
This is not taken into account the size for the solid, $V_s$. Since the solid use the Einstein model I don't exactly know how can I introduce $V_s$ to find the equations of state and then equilibrium equations between this two parts

Comment: Your expression for $Z_s$ does not depend on the size, while $Z_g$ does. You need to fix this asymmetry if you want to make progress. Notice, however, that this is not the right way to ask the question. Check-my-calculations questions are not within this site policy. Try to recast your question in a more general form, stressing the conceptual issues.

Comment: @GiorgioP Thank you for your remark. I would like to understand better the equilibrium between systems using statistical mechanics, could you please tell me about some reference when I can find a good explanation or examples about it? I think the problem is that I not enough familiar with this kind of problems and I'm trying to do my best by myself